# avoid rvalue template deduction

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

I have a class template that wants to take an iterator type with an auto deduction from the constructor.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
  Foo(T a);
}
```

If I have the following, `T` will be `std::vector<int>::iterator`:

```
std::vector<int> vector;
auto I = vector.begin();
auto ptr = new Foo(I);
```

However, if I pass rvalue, `T` will be `std::vector<int>::iterator&&`

```
std::vector<int> vector;
auto ptr = new Foo(vector.begin());
```

How can I force each deduction to remove the `&&`? I simply just want to keep the iterator type where the copy is cheap.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't give your variable the same name as the type.  At least call it `myvector` or something.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if I pass rvalue, `T` will be `std::vector<int>::iterator&&`

No. `T` is *not* a reference type (does not have `&&`), so it will *still* be deduced as `std::vector<int>::iterator`, your assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::remove_reference` to strip the type of references (see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference)):

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(T a);
};

template <typename T>
Foo<std::remove_reference<T>> *build_foo(T value)
{
    // operations ...
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector;
    auto ptr = build_foo(vector.begin());
}
```

Here we create a `Foo` builder function that removes the references from the given type and returns a constructed `Foo`.